# Windows 7 and wallpaper folders

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I try to change my desktop wallpaper and I cannot choose a different folder from the one I chose at first...

When I first installed W7 I changed the wallpaper by right-clicking in the desktop and choosing Customize (maybe it's not correct because I use the italian version) and then Change Wallpaper in the bottom and finally I browsed for a folder with some images in and chose the wallpaper. When I do the same exact things now, the folder I select in the final pass is not selected: I mean its pictures are not shown and it doesn't appear in the drop-down list.

I can put a specific picture as a wallpaper by selecting it through Explorer, and some times (not always) the folder shows in the drop-down list.

Is there any possible solution to this?

Comment: (In the English installation the word is "Personalise")

Comment: Based on your results with the answer below, I fear this is a bug/working as intended, so will have to wait what they do with this in a month or two

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem with not being able to browse for a different folder for background images. Turns out it happened after I removed the Pictures library. Simply using the 'Restore default libraries' command seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could place you own wallpaper images under "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper", that's the location Windows is using for the images shown in the list.

Comment: I know that... but I don't want my photos mixed up and/or duplicated. I just want to keep my photos in their original position... The problem is that Windows should let me select a folder (otherwise why have they put the Browse button?)... and it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to keep my photos in their original position
>   - I'm looking at the path: Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Desktop Background

If you desire to keep your pictures where they are then consider adding directory to your photo library.  (select the library, properties, include folder)
'Choose your desktop background', picture location: picture library (select pictures)
While, I still don't fully understand the Libraries, I am finding the concept more appealing as it allows me to keep a secondary structuring when booting an alternate OS.

But if you desire any of MS's released wallpaper packs, this might not be what you desire.

(How must it be before it is considered necromancy to reply to a question?)

Comment: I disabled the libraries because everything in my hard disk is already organized in folders... But I can't add any folder in the "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Desktop Background" window although I selected it through the Browse button.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this guide [how to add pictures into the existing themes](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/08/how-to-add-more-wallpapers-to-existing-themes-in-windows-7/) and [How to Create and Share Themes in Windows 7](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/08/how-to-create-and-share-themes-in-windows-7/)

Hope those will help you :)

Comment: Option 1 of the guide was already proposed by TFM: I don't want my photos mixed up together.
My problem is that the folder selected through Browse button (Option 2 of the guide) doesn't show up, so I can't choose any of its pictures.