# Custom Windows 7 wallpapers location

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

I would like to add a custom folder location as the source for my Windows 7 Desktop Background (wallpapers), so that Windows 7 can auto-switch all the pictures in that path to set as wallpaper.

In the 'Control Panel- Choose your desktop background', there is a Browse button, that seems to allow me to browse to a custom location (for e.g. d:\wallpapers), but it does not seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn’t work? What happens when you try? That **should** work; when you select a folder, Windows should allow you to use whatever’s in there as a slideshow and remember the folder in the future.

Comment: After browsing to my custom folder containing all my wallpapers, it doesn't show any of those wallpapers for me to select.

Comment: ? Create subfolder in your Images folder, put your images there and try again... On the desktop, right click -> personalized... :)

Answer (score 1):

The default place for wallpapers is in the Windows directory:

```
%windir%\Web\Wallpaper
```

If you have administrator rights, it is easy to make additional folders there - e.g. Nature, Travel, Sea, Mountain, Space, etc. Place nice well-formatted JPEGs there. There is [a Microsoft site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/personalize/wallpaper-desktop-background) that provides beautiful ones in 1920x1200 (Widescreen format).

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I can change the location as follows:

Right click `Desktop` -> `Personalize` -> click `Desktop Background` -> click `Browse` -> Choose the location (whatever folder you need).

It should populate and allow you to switch between like the default desktop does. I confirmed it worked on my 32-bit build.

Comment: That's the exact steps I take, but it doesn't show my custom wallpapers. Perhaps I have too many other customizations like Custopacks installed on my system, screwing up Windows...

Answer (score 0):

just to answer this problem: there is another thread that describes the same problem and provides a solution that worked for me and others:
[Windows 7 and wallpaper folders](https://superuser.com/questions/28764/windows-7-and-wallpaper-folders)

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called desktop fusion that allows you to change it easily. I would recommend trying that, works pretty well for me c: